# Query Multiple Inputs against multiple columns in SQL Database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Going to try and describe my issue as easy as i can...

I have 4 inputs where the user can choose from a drop down list. For example say the user chooses

Input1 = red

Input2 = blue

Input3 = yellow

Input4 = gold

my tables looks like this atm,

Mixed colours

```
colour_id |
colour_name |
Number_of_colours |
Colour 1 |
Colour 2 |
Colour 3 |
Colour 4 |


<br /><br />  And the data<br /><br /> 
001 |
Mucky Brown |
4 |
Red |
blue |
yellow |
gold |
<br>

002 |
Light Purple |
3 |
Red |
blue |
white |
{empty cell} |



<br /><br/>
```

Colour list_tb

Colourist_Id /
Colour_name

001 / red
002 / blue
003 / yellow
004 / gold

Crossreferencing_tb 
Colour_I'd /
Colourlist_I'd /
Crossreferencing_id

First thing i want is to see if theres a colour that uses the 4 colours that the user has selected so thats a stright forward

`SELECT * FROM colours_tb WHERE Colour 1 ='red' And Colour 2 ='blue' and Colour 3 ='yellow' and Colour 4 ='gold'`, (I've got this bit working)

My next query is i want to check if theirs a colour that only requires 3 out of 4 inputs selected. I'm guessing I would need 3 tables like above? (my goal is to list all permutations of colours that can be made by the 4 selected disregarding singles)

how would i go about doing this, i can only assume it would include some while loops that check the number of colours colum and add +1 to some sort of count that would be defined.

I have thought long and hard about this but unable to get near an answer.

Any input would be a great help.

Im using php.

Comment: Normalize your DB first by having an intermediate table... (extra_colors-->combinations<--colors)

Comment: That's not your actual query is it? `SELECT * WHERE Colour 1 ='red' Colour 2 ='blue' Colour 3 ='yellow' Colour 4 ='gold',` - You've a few `AND`'s and/or `OR`'s missing.

Comment: No I was just cutting down text

Comment: "a colour that only requires 3 out of 4 inputs selected" is not clear.  What does it mean?

Comment: I want all variations of colours possible with the 4 selected excluding single colours

Answer (score 0):

As KA_lin said, you have to create 2 more tables so you can build a many-to-many relationship. Then, you would count the number of primary colours by some query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM IntermediateTable I
  INNER JOIN CompositeColoursTable C
  ON C.Id = I.IdCompositeColour
WHERE C.name = x         -> eg "Mucky Brown"
```

If you want to have the number of colours always available in your future queries, you could also build a view returning the composite colours + the query if the COUNT function.

---

After comment below. Ok, I'm understanding you want also the contrary, ie, "given n colors, which composite colour have these n?". For that, you'll need a query like this:

```
SELECT C.name
FROM IntermediateTable I
  INNER JOIN CompositeColoursTable C
    ON C.Id = I.IdCompositeColour
  INNER JOIN PrimaryColoursTable P
    ON P.Id = I.IdPrimaryColour
WHERE (P.Name=ColourList(1) or ColourList(1)='') OR
      (P.Name=ColourList(2) or ColourList(2)='') OR
      (P.Name=ColourList(3) or ColourList(3)='') OR
      (P.Name=ColourList(4) or ColourList(4)='')
```

Observation: ColourList is where user chooses values from, and would evaluate in the query as 'Red', 'Blue', 'Gold', etc. If not selected/empty cell, returns '' (you could also customize this).

(I don't have SQL here, so please test it first)

Comment: I've added to my question, I knew I had to. Sorry for missing it out. On my phone atm. Hard to type stuff out, no excuse though

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try and implement it, i will let you know how I get on.